# Running a Python Exe through Excel / Command Prompt can't find file but running it normally in file explorer works

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba

I have a python script which I have turned into an Exe with the hope of running it through Excel VBA. As the first line, it attempts to load in a csv file with
inputs = pd.read_csv("file.csv") Where file.csv is a data file in the same directory.
When I turn it into an exe it works when I try to run it through double clicking in File Explorer, however when I tried to run it through Excel using the Shell Command I get the error saying it cannot find the file.csv (FileNotFoundError). I figured out that the same thing occurs when I try to run the exe using Command Prompt.
Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you got the current working directory as the directory containing the csv?

Comment: I am not sure what the issue exactly is but probably has to do with the path variables used in either case. In your python file, try putting the full path of the csv file (even though it is in the same folder) and see if that works.

Comment: @elbashmubarmeg, So putting the full path of the CSV file in the python code works, but the problem is that I am wanting this to be a file I can move around and give to people who don't know python.

Comment: @Jacob In pycharm the current working directory is the directory in question and that is also where the exe is located. Are you suggesting I may need to add a line in the python script to set the working directory to its current location?

Comment: So I managed to get it to work simply by changing the directory in Excel using 
ChDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path). I had assumed it would default to the directory of the file but clearly not. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.